# How to get owners information for sas file in Windows SAS?

Tags: windows, sas, file-ownership

Is there a way to find the information about owner of sas file in Windows SAS?
I tried the following code But it doesnt give any information about the owner of code.

```
data info;
   length infoname infoval $300;
   drop rc fid infonum i close;
   rc=filename('abc','C:\c-ae.sas');
   fid=fopen('abc');
   infonum=foptnum(fid);
   do i=1 to infonum;
      infoname=foptname(fid,i);
      infoval=finfo(fid,infoname);
      output;
   end;
   close=fclose(fid);
run;
```

Is there any way I can get information about the owner of the code/file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can get the file owner from a SAS file property.  However, you can use the Windows `DIR` command with the `/Q` switch to discover the owner.  For example:

```
filename x pipe 'dir /q c:\c-ae.sas';
data a;
   infile x firstobs=6 truncover;
   input @1 file_date yymmdd10.
        @13 file_time time8.
            file_size
            file_owner $22.
            file_name $32.;
   format file_date yymmdd10. file_time time8.; 
   output;
   stop;
run;
filename x clear;
```

The `/B` switch is supposed to suppress the command header and trailer output, but it does not on my system; hence, using `firstobs=6` skips the headers and the `stop` command skips the rest of the output.

Note that this is really a Windows solution, not really SAS.  I'll add the `Windows` tags in case others can chip in.

Comment: Agh! That's a much better method than mine.  I need to work on my google skills...